# Existing photometry data of the open star cluster Cepheus OB3?

Tags: astronomy, photometry, star-clusters

I am doing research with my teacher on photometry of the [open star cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_cluster) [Cepheus OB3](http://www.astro.ex.ac.uk/people/timn/Catalogues/Clusters/cepheus-ob3.html), and we are trying to find research papers so we can target stars in the photos we took.

Are there any existing resources available on this matter?

Answer (score 1):

Google uncovered [this website](http://www.astro.ex.ac.uk/people/timn/Catalogues/Clusters/cepheus-ob3.html) from a group at the University of Exeter that has photometry. The format for the files is found [here](http://www.astro.ex.ac.uk/people/timn/Catalogues/format.html).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I agree in general, but as the question was asked, the link is essentially the answer.

Comment: I understand the case, I'm just trying to encourage _more awesome_ answers. (:

Comment: I'd be happy to delete my answer if you want to provide an awesome answer to this question. I provided the answer that I thought this question was both looking for and deserved. I reserve my awesome answers for good questions.